# Kicked out of dota 2 game after 30 seconds

Tags: steam, technical-issues, dota-2

I managed to get an invite to dota 2 on steam and everything downloaded successfully.  But now when I start it up and enter a game, I get kicked out while waiting for the match to start.  I just have a connection error (starts to count down).  It's odd because it happens within the same 30 seconds every time so it can't just be a fluctuation in my internet.

Anyone else have this sort of trouble?  I've heard it can be from steam but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: check your firewall, see if DOTA2 is on the allowed list?

Comment: yeah it is, that didn't work

Comment: you should activate net_graph to get more information.
go to steam and rightclick dota 2-> properties-> start param -> enter `-console` and start the game. write `net_graph 1` into the console.

Comment: correction: you should use `net_graph 3` for more details. `net_graph 0` can hide it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this happen to me. After you patch, Dota sometimes fails to recognize that you have the most up-to-date patch. It's frustrating because you don't get an error message that would lead you to this. However, it can be solved.

Simply log out of your game, go to your steam library and right click Dota 2. Select Preferences, and find "Revalidate Game Cache", this will force your game to re-update, and should solve your problem.

Comment: No problem, I've had it happen to me a couple times, let me know if it works out!

Comment: oddly enough it started updating when i opened steam up today.  we'll see how it goes

Comment: shiz it didn't work, still got kicked out and wouldn't let me rejoin the game